# How to retrieve the android sdk version in an ionic framework application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic application where i require the android sdk version inorder to provide runtime permissions for API23 and above.
Please suggest how can i do the same in cordova.
Help would be appreciated!!!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use `$ionicPlatform`.

`ionic.Platform.version()`